# Word for dead or dormant, but not definitively one or the other?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, adjectives

Is there a word that means dead *or* dormant/sleeping/inert but potentially alive?

Example:

> "I carefully approached the __________ [dead, or alive-but-at-rest]
>   mouse in the corner."

Inert or quiescent come close, but they can't *also* mean definitively dead, if that is found to be the case. If the mouse were found to be dead, "inert" wouldn't be the appropriate word. Is there a word that approximates both simultaneously?

Comment: Thanks @sumelic! I edited my comment with an example, and a bit more info. Hope that helps.

Comment: Possibly a synonym of *inert* will work here... Maybe "motionless"?

Comment: You could also use 'latent'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from *motionless* (as already mentioned in another answer), ***still , immobile & lifeless*** work here. Especially, *lifeless* has the ambiguity you desire. *Stationary* can be used too but I recall it being used more for inanimate objects.

> "I carefully approached the ***lifeless/still/immobile*** mouse in the corner."

ODO:

> **[lifeless](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/lifeless)**
>   *ADJECTIVE*
>
> **1** Dead or *apparently* dead.
>
> ‘When firefighters pulled his lifeless body from the river, his heart
>   wasn't beating and paramedics feared the worst as he was taken to
>   hospital unconscious.’
>
> **[still](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/still#still-2)**
>   *ADJECTIVE*
>
> **1** Not moving or making a sound.
>   ‘the still body of the young man’
>
> **[immobile](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/immobile)**
>   *ADJECTIVE*
>
> **1** Not moving; motionless.
>
> ‘The body is so mute, so immobile that one might think she is dead.’

Answer (score 0):

I'd be inclined to use "motionless".  Even a living creature has slight movements (e.g. respiration).